# Noisy graphics card - any fix?

Tags: nvidia-geforce

I have an Nvidia 950 in my new laptop, and it appears as though the graphics card is causing noise on the audio bus, this noise happens when the screen/parts of the screen are redrawn, and also happens with the headphones plugged in.
I can get around it somewhat by disabling hardware acceleration in chrome since that's where I watch videos/listen at the same time. However, it seems better on windows than mint 18 and better with the nouveau driver than the proprietary one. 
I may just be imagining all the situations that improve it, but is there any fix/is this a common problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're getting audio interference from the card. Getting an external DAC (*Digital-to Analog Converter*)  would solve this.